# Remove menu by clicking on document jQuery

Tags: jquery, menu, click

I'm learning jQuery and I'm tying something out.

I've created a slide in menu by clicking on menu. Now is have 2 events .click, one for slide in and 1 for slide out. When I click on the menu than opens the menu and directly closing it.

How can i prevent that? I want to have it like this. When yo click anywhere on the the menu will slide out.

Can you help me?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Button fade by mouse enter
$("#menubutton").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#menubutton").fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
});

//Slide in menu by clicking on menu
$("#menubutton").click(function(){
    $("#menu").slideToggle('slide');    
});

//Back to normal after mouse leave
$("#menubutton").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#menubutton").fadeTo('slow' , 1);
});

$(document).click(function(){
    $("#menu").slideUp("slow");
});


});
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your button click propagates to the document element, so it triggers it's sliding up handler too. You should prevent that propagation:

```
//Slide in menu by clicking on menu
$("#menubutton").click(function(event){
    $("#menu").slideToggle('slide');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TXXZq/)